# Can an ADS1231 be used in place of an ADS1115?

Tags: adc

I have a working millivolt recording device which uses the [ADS1115](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1115.pdf) 16-bit adc. I would like to move up in resolution to the [ADS1231](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/ads1231.pdf) which is 24-bit. The Ads1115 is described as an i2c-compatible serial interface device using SDA and SCL lines to the microcomputer. I've never used the ADS1231. It is described as a "two-wire serial digital interface" using SCLK, DRDY/DOUT, CLKIN lines. Does this mean its easy to exchange chips or next to impossible?

Comment: If you are referring to specific ICs, then please post links to their datasheets.  This would save folks some looking up, time and clicks.  Folks out here appreciate that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Does this mean its easy to exchange chips or next to impossible?"

That of course depends on your level of expertise, invested development effort (PCB made? code completed?) and the amount of rework effort you are prepared to spend.

Those chips come in different housing, so if a PCB has been made it will need rework. They also use a totally different communication protocol, so if software has been written it will need rework. The 1115 has a much higher maximum data rate, so that might also be a problem. I have not looked at the electrical interface :)

But you could have concluded this all yourself after a 60 seconds scan through the two datasheets!

Comment: Thanks Wouter, "totally different communication protocol". That answered my question.